# What is getCompoundDrawables() in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

How `getCompoundDrawables()` is used in Android:

```
if(mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null)
    mEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_face, 0);
```

I wanted to check whether there is a drawable in `EditText` at the end of it. Is the if condition giving the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the correct way to find out whether a compound drawable is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
Drawable drawable =  getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_face);
drawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()));
if(mEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null)
 {
    mEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
 }
mEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Drawable co =  v.getCompoundDrawables()[2];
        if (co == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }
        if (event.getX() > v.getMeasuredWidth() - v.getPaddingRight()
                - co.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
            //code for right drawable event
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```